# Problem with sprites in Unity 2020.2.0a13

Tags: unity-game-engine

When starting a project on the sprite, extraneous pixels appear, on the old version of unity, in the same project there was no such problem, please tell me how to solve this problem. (Sprites are on the button).

Here are two screenshots, on the first one on the left how sprites look before the project is turned on, on the right after it is turned on.

The second shows the settings for sprites.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wxpb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve7WZ.png)

Comment: Does your sprite have any extraneous pixels? Or is it a clean rectangle?

Comment: Is this sprite from a spritesheet?

Comment: @MathewHD square sprite, 32 by 32 pixels, background transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by installing "Use Sprite Mesh" in the component "Image"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1IKH.png)